# Named ranges resulting in errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple piece of code, just trying to determine if a change was made to a named cell.  Of course most cells do not have names associated with them resulting in err 1004.  None of the error trapping methods seems to work (on error resume next, on error goto 0).  How do I solve this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Target.Name.Name = "IDLOPT" Then Call ChangeToLine
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` works for me.

Comment: I have tried this but got the same err 1004.  The answer from TechnoDabbler works

Comment: Thankk you fro your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("IDLOPT")) Is Nothing Then
        Call ChangeToLine
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Name.Name = "IDLOPT" Then
        If Err = 0 Then Call ChangeToLine
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this but got the same err 1004.  The answer from TechnoDabbler works

Comment: @Filiep Samyn I don't believe that you tried my solution. Therefore I also don't believe that it failed you. I'm very confident of this because I did try and I know it works. However, I did up-vote Techno-Dabbler's answer, not because it works better but because it has the better logic, and think you should mark it as accepted. That's how answers are rewarded on this forum.

Comment: Yes I did try it. I would never provide feedback without trying a suggested solution. I use Office 2016 professional. I can provide the file and screenshot but don't seem to be able to add those as part of my reply. Feel free to email me at fhsamyn@gmail.com and I will reply with the file attached